# How to sum array values by monthly basis in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

```
[

    {
      "id": 200,
      "date_created": "2021-01-14T17:15:55",
      "sale": "2500.00",
    },
    {
      "id": 201,
      "date_created": "2021-01-15T15:10:30",
      "sale": "2000.00",
    },
    {
      "id": 202,
      "date_created": "2021-02-4T11:14:10",
      "sale": "4000.00",
    }
]
```

I am unable to sum it by the monthly basis in react js or next js.

Can someone guide me on how can I do it in React?

I want the output as:
**monthly basis.**

For Jan total sum = 4500

For Feb total sum = 4000

etc...

Comment: did you mean to sum the "sale" value? you can use Javascript reduce method.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[mre]" and all their linked pages. You've given us data, but show no attempt to solve the problem, which makes it look like you didn't try.

Answer (score 0):

You have to browse your array and to add each sale.

Example :

```js
const a = [

{
  "id": 200,
  "date_created": "2021-01-14T17:15:55",
  "sale": "2500.00",
},
{
  "id": 201,
  "date_created": "2021-01-15T15:10:30",
  "sale": "2000.00",
},
{
  "id": 202,
  "date_created": "2021-02-4T11:14:10",
  "sale": "4000.00",
}
]


const sum = a.reduce((previous, current) => previous + new Number(current.sale), 0)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: but this gives me total sum of all.
How can I do it monthly basis.
For Jan total sum = 4500
For Feb total sum = 4000 etc...